# How does python have different data types in an array?

Tags: python, c, arrays

Python can have a list with different data types in it i.e. [1,"two",3]. Python was implemented in c, so how would I create an array with different data types in it using c?

Comment: By implementing and then using Python. Seriously, don't try this. The *entire reason you are using a language* like C, where you have to write out the type of everything, is so that the type of everything can be determined at compile-time. This is impossible for the mixed-type list except in thoroughly useless cases (where you really want a `struct`), so you end up having to write types for everything *and* write code that figures out what the types of things are inside the list at runtime *and* get undefined behaviour if you're wrong instead of getting an exception. The worst of every world.

Comment: @user1163114:  Please explain *why* you want to do this.  There's probably a more C-ish way of accomplishing your goals.

Answer (score 4):

So, I have no idea how it is implemented in Python, but in C there are ways to operate on generic data. in its most simple form:

```
void *array[size];
```

Now you have an array full of `void*`.  Each `void*` can point to anything.  You would want some extra information as well to tell you the size of the thing it points to.

```
typedef struct {
    void *data;
    size_t size;
} elem;
```

You could represent the actual type if needed via a variety of methods.  You can use unions to hold one of N types in the same variable. Anyway, the point is that there are various ways to do operate on generic data in C.

Answer (score 3):

What if your array consisted of C structs of the form:

```
struct slot {
  int type;
  char *data;
};
```

Now you have an array that can contain arbitrary types of data, as long as you can represent them as pointers-to-char.

This isn't, of course, how Python does it; the point is that there doesn't have to be any connection between how your application handles data and how your implementation language handles data.

Answer (score 3):

> how would I create an array with different data types in it using c?

You can't; C is a statically-typed language.

You can, however, use things like unions:

```
typedef union {
    int i;
    float f;
} Foo;


Foo array[3];

array[0].i = 3;
array[1].f = 4.2;
...
```

You can also use `void *` to point at any objects you like, but this requires careful memory management.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there are no “raw” values; everything is an object and knows its type. Even integers are objects (try printing `(1).__class__` or `1 .__class__`). Everything you do in C with Python objects, you do through a `PyObject *` (a pointer to the object).¹

A Python `list` is a dynamic (i.e. resizable) array of `PyObject *`. Since every object knows its type, the `list` doesn't have to be declared as having members of a specific type.

¹ Also note: Python does not have “variables” in the usual sense (C, BASIC, Pascal etc), where a typed variable contains a value; it has namespaces and names (actually, dictionaries mapping strings to objects; a namespace is a dictionary, its keys are the names, its values are the pointers to the objects pointed to by each name).